# AWS CodeBuild COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR: Error while executing command: ng build --prod --aot. Reason: exit status 1

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I am trying to use codebuild to build an Angular 8 project. I've tried to use ng build --prod and ng build --prod --aot in my buildspec and it still fails with COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR: Error while executing command: ng build --prod --aot. Reason: exit status 1. I've looked and I can't find the exact issue I've had on SO. I don't want to waste my free build time so below is my build spec

```
version: 0.2
environment_variables:
    plaintext:
        S3_BUCKET: "example.com"
        BUILD_ENV: "prod"
phases:
    install:
        runtime-versions:
            java: ${JAVA}
        commands:
            - echo Installing source NPM dependencies...
            - npm install
            - npm install -g @angular/cli
    build:
        commands:
            - echo Build started on `date`
            - ng build --prod --aot
    post_build:
         commands:
            - echo Build completed on `date`
```

Comment: exit 1 is a generic error that indicates the command failed. Try running the 'ng' command with some debugging option to see why the command execution is failing.